# Conditinal format if text contains A but not B

Tags: google-sheets

so I got this big table and want to use conditional formatting to highlight some words.

Example Cells:

House [2] | Garden [4] | Household [5]

Now, i want to highlight every cell, that "text contains "House"" - but not if it is "Household". Is there any way to do that with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Please try a CF custom formula rule of:

```
=countif(A1,"House *")>0
```

The wildcard (`*`) allows for the numbers that are in the same cell and the space rules out words that start with `House` but are of more than five letters. Won't handle the likes of `Chouse`, but then you have not mentioned the like in the OP.